# tinymce getcontent not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

```
tinymce.get('content').getContent
```

is not working.

Here is my code.  you can see all the different comments for different things I have tried.  I have

`alert('end');`

at the end just as a test to see if the code is working.  Currently it is not unless i comment out anything related to tinymce that is not the initializer.  These functions are inside of document ready.

Why wont tinymce getcontent work?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            inline: true
        });
        //$('input').keyup(function () {
        //    //alert("keyed");
        //    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').val($(this).val());
        //});        
        //$('.artBodyText').keyup(function () {
        //    alert("keyed");
        //    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').val($(this).val());
        //});
        //$('#mytextarea').keyup(function () {
        //    alert("keyed");
        //    $('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').val($(this).val());
        //});
      // var x = tinymce.get('#mytextarea').getContent();
        //var y = $('mytextarea').tinymce().getContent();
        alert(tinymce.get('mytextarea').getContent());
        alert("end");
    });
</script>
```

Is it someting to do with firefox or the way I am loading the editor?   Note - the editor works on my form very nicely for submitting and posting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call `getContent()` before the editor is fully initialized.  The `init()` method is **asynchronous** and I would suspect your alert is running before the editor is fully initialized.

The easiest way to make sure that you are waiting until the editor is fully initialized is to rely on the init event that the editor provides:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#myTextarea',
  ...
  ...
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function () {
      // This is a common function for loading initial content into TinyMCE 
      editor.setContent('Using the on init stuff!');
      // You could run your alert here as you know the editor in initialized
      alert(tinymce.get('mytextarea').getContent());
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You are correct.  So how do I use GetContent if i need to tell another function, like this one:  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){ //EVENT }; to wait and not fire until the initializer is complete.

Comment: Can you just trigger that other function from the init function in TinyMCE?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It is a tab view, when one tab loads I want it to 'setcontent' from data in the other tab, so I almost need two triggers.  I suppose I could set a switch at the end of the initializer and then check if the switch is set to ON before I run the tab change trigger, but it seems like a lot of unneccesary code

Comment: Perhaps you can just disable the tabs until the editor is fully initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetTimeout` on it, because the editor loads the `textarea` very late, and it takea up to 5000 millisecond to fully load TinyMCE. In that case, your code without timing will run before the editor; that's why you have to delay the `get()` and `getContent()`.